# Does "@synthesize" every "@property" necessary?

Tags: objective-c

I'm following one of the iOS tutorials from Ray Wenderlich ([Scarybugs part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-part-1)). But I notice for each property in the model, he always "@synthesize" it in the implementation.

Here is the example of the models:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RWTScaryBugData : NSObject

@property (strong) NSString *title;
@property (assign) float rating;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title rating:(float)rating;

@end
```

--

```
#import "RWTScaryBugData.h"

@implementation RWTScaryBugData

@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize rating = _rating;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title rating:(float)rating {
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    self.title = title;
    self.rating = rating;
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

--

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class RWTScaryBugData;

@interface RWTScaryBugDoc : NSObject

@property (strong) RWTScaryBugData *data;
@property (strong) UIImage *thumbImage;
@property (strong) UIImage *fullImage;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title rating:(float)rating thumbImage:(UIImage *)thumbImage fullImage:(UIImage *)fullImage;

@end
```

--

```
#import "RWTScaryBugDoc.h"
#import "RWTScaryBugData.h"

@implementation RWTScaryBugDoc
@synthesize data = _data;
@synthesize thumbImage = _thumbImage;
@synthesize fullImage = _fullImage;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title rating:(float)rating thumbImage:(UIImage *)thumbImage fullImage:(UIImage *)fullImage {  
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    self.data = [[RWTScaryBugData alloc] initWithTitle:title rating:rating];
    self.thumbImage = thumbImage;
    self.fullImage = fullImage;
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

I know "@synthesize" is basically to allocate an instance variable for a property, but it has been taken care of by default for every "@property" in ".h file" (although not visible).

My questions is: is it necessary to "@synthesize" every "@property" we have in our public API? (I tried deleting all the "@synthesize" in the implementation, and it still worked)

Comment: I'm going to comment, instead of answer to let a more knowledgeable person give a real answer but in my experience developing for iOS I've not had to do any synthesis unless the properties were attached to an `@protocol` and not part of the public `@interface`. Newer versions of clang (IIRC) handle the synthesis automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html), automatic synthesis of property instance variables was introduced with Xcode 4.4 (LLVM Compiler 4.0) and requires the modern runtime (all code on iOS, 64-bit code on OS X).

So, the tutorial is a bit dated, that's all.

Comment: That's the answer I wanted to hear. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`@synthesize` is no longer needed. The compiler will synthesize the getter and setter as required with an instance variable named as `_<propertyName>` automatically. It creates the instance variable but more importantly it creates the getter and setter methods (for readwrite properties).

If you've manually provided the getter/setter for a property, then an instance variable won't be automatically synthesized, and you'll need to add the @synthesize statement. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html):

> Note: The compiler will automatically synthesize an instance variable in all situations where it’s also synthesizing at least one accessor method. If you implement both a getter and a setter for a readwrite property, or a getter for a readonly property, the compiler will assume that you are taking control over the property implementation and won’t synthesize an instance variable automatically.
>   If you still need an instance variable, you’ll need to request that one be synthesized:
>   @synthesize property = _property;

Comment: What is difference between property = _property; are both same ? Why to use _ ?

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help  little more.

@property(nonatomic) NSString *name;

the `@property` is an Objective-C directive which declares the property

```
-> The "`nonatomic`" in the parenthesis specifies that the property is non-atomic in nature.
-> and then we define the type and name  of our property.
-> prototyping of getter and setter method
```

now go to .m file

previously we have synthesis this property by using `@synthesis` , now it also ***NOT*** required , it automatically done by IDE.

-> this `@synthesis` now generate the getter and setter(if not readonly) methods.

and Then why we  even write `@synthesis` in our code if it always done by IDE .

one of the basic use is :-

what our IDE do internally

```
@synthesis name=_name;
```

we use _name to access particular property but now you want synthesis by some other way like
`firstname`  you can do it like

```
@synthesis name= firstname
```

or just by name

```
@synthesis name=name
```

So from it you can access this property as you want.